# Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix, s.t. $p(x)=(x-\lambda)^2$ is its characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $\dim\ker(\lambda I-A)=1$, and $v_1\in\ker(\lambda I-A)$; $v_1\neq0$.

Also, we know that, then, $\dim\ker(\lambda I-A)^2=2$. Take $v_2\in \ker(\lambda I-A)^2\setminus\ker(\lambda I-A)$; $v_n\neq 0$.

Why can one say that $Av_2=v_1+\lambda v_2$?

I know that $Av_2\in\ker(\lambda I-A)^2$, then there are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ s.t.
$$Av_2=\alpha v_1+\beta v_2$$
bu how can one conclude that $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=\lambda$?

I'm trying to understand Jordan Normal Form. Because we know that in this case $$J=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 1\\
0 & \lambda\end{array}\right),$$
in a way that $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is its Jordan basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
0=(\lambda I-A)^2v_2=(\lambda I-A)\,(\lambda I-A)v_2.
$$
This shows that $(\lambda I-A)v_2\in\ker(\lambda I-A)$. Since $\dim\ker(\lambda I-A)=1$, any vector in it is a scalar multiple of $v_1$. Thus
$$
(\lambda I-A)v_2=\alpha\,v_1
$$
for some scalar $\alpha$. This we can rewrite as 
$$
Av_2= - \alpha v_1 + \lambda v_2. 
$$
Note that the constant in front of $v_1$ cannot be avoided if you are taking $v_1$ as *any* element of $\ker(\lambda I-A)$ and $v_2$ as *any* element of $\ker (\lambda I-A)^2$.

**Edit:** Carl's comment.

Now, if we allow ourselves to choose $v_2$, then we can replace the $v_2$ above by $v_2/(-\alpha)$, and then the formula becomes
$$
Av_2=v_1+\lambda v_2. 
$$
Note that  $\alpha\ne0$, because otherwise $v_2$ would be an eigenvector for $\lambda$, which it is not by choice.

Comment: As to why $\alpha=1$, first of all note that if $\alpha=0$, then $v_2$ would be an eigenvector itself (which it isn't). Hence, you can divide both sides of the equation by $-\alpha$ to get $$A \cdot {v_2 \over -\alpha} = v_1 + \lambda \cdot {v_2 \over -\alpha},$$ so if we use $\displaystyle v_2'= {v_2 \over -\alpha}$ instead of $v_2$, then $$Av_2' = v_1 + \lambda v_2'.$$

Comment: And thanks for the shorter solution! I was about to post an algebraic monstrosity ...

Comment: Thanks, Carl. I incorporated your comment in the answer.